# rotating an edge without thining the shape

Tags: modeling, edges

when we rotate edge, they keep the same size so the shape of the mesh change. is it possible to scale the edge to keep the same shape while rotating it ? [image][image]
That's the result I want to get with the rotation
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use "shear" which is part of the 2.8 new gyzmos:

[image]

Note that it works for more complex shapes, and you can do it in the direction you want:

[image]

For 2.79, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> (yes only that), then choose X or Y axis to do nearly the same.